# How many parameters in my mixed effect model (for t-tests)

Tags: r, t-test

I have the following mixed effect model;

```
penicillin_model = lmer(yield ~ treat + (1 | blend),
                    data = penicillin)
```

Treat contains 4 categories and blend contains 5 categories, am I correct in thinking that there are 9 parameters in my model? (one as the intercept, 3 fixed effects and 5 variances)? or would i need to add an error term? Hope that makes sense.

```
df = nrow(penicillin) - 9

#calculate p-value by comparing the t-value against the df
1 - pt(0.3643396, df) #treat B
1 - pt(1.8216981, df) #treat C
1 - pt(0.7286793, df) #treat D
```

model output

[image]

Comment: Look in the output. How many parameters do you see? (Count the fixed effects, count the random effects).

Comment: @JeremyMiles Ok, so I have 4 fixed effects (one in the intercept) but the random effects are confusing me a little, would this be 5 as i have 5 types of blend or 2 as in the output i have 2 groups (blend and residual). I have updated the question with this info in the output

Comment: There are no parameters you can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four fixed effects - one for each level of group (well, except the reference, but this is replaced by the intercept).

You have two random effects: random intercept (of blend) and residual.

$4 + 2 = 6$ parameters.